# Classifying objects based of a varying number of the same type of feature vector for each object

Tags: machine-learning, classification, categorical-data, natural-language

For a congressional session, I have created a doc2vec model of speeches made. Using the vectors from this model, I have a dataset of each congressperson, their political affiliation, and a list of the vector representations of each speech they made. Each of these document vector representations is a 300 element vector.

I am now trying to classify each congressperson by party using these document vectors representing their speeches. So far I have tried using the mean vector for each speaker, but I was looking for ways to use the whole set of vectors each person has.

Comment: So you are doing supervised learning, right? You could train the model on the speech-level (i.e. not on the person level) and then, for each person in the test set, aggregate (e.g. average) the probabilities of their speeches.